# Creating a Number Changer with TextInput in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying create a Number Incrementor/Decrementor with the use of Text Input and 2 Touch Highlights "+" and "-".

```
<TextInput
  keyboardType='number-pad'
  value={this.state.textValue}
  onChangeText={this.updateText}
  style={styles.textInput}
/>

<TouchableHighlight
  style={styles.button}
  onPress={this.increment}>
    <Text style={styles.buttonTextFill}>+</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>

<TouchableHighlight
  style={styles.button}
  onPress={this.decrement}>
    <Text style={styles.buttonTextFill}>-</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

And I use the following methods:

```
updateText: function (text) {
    this.setState({textValue: text});
},

decrement: function () {
    this.setState({textValue: this.state.textValue - 1});
},

increment: function () {
    this.setState({textValue: this.state.textValue + 1});
},
```

Also I have set **textValue** as a state in getInitialState function and set it to 0.

Why isn't this working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you seeing it do when you touch the + or -?

Comment: looks fine. Do some chrome dev tools debugging.

Comment: @rmevans9 Hey, when I click + the text from the text input disappears while - makes it append a 1 (Ex: 2 will become 21)

Comment: @rmevans9 But if I print the state in a <Text> it does the increment and decrement perfectly. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem that TextInput is not a fan of the value being a number. I put a .toString() on the value of the TextInput and everything started working as expected. In addition you need to convert the string value to a number in the on change since TextInput passes a string when you change it.

The new Update method:

```
updateText: function (text) {
    this.setState({textValue: +text});
},
```

The new TextInput:

```
<TextInput
    keyboardType='number-pad'
    value={this.state.textValue.toString()}
    onChangeText={this.updateText}
    style={styles.textInput}
/>
```

https://rnplay.org/apps/ZNcwSg

Comment: Thank you. And yes, Text Input is favourable to Strings.

Comment: Hey @rmevans9, why u write `+text` it's work for me but why we add `+` ?

Comment: @OliverD `onChangeText` returns a string. In the example provided the state is a number. Doing `+` before a string makes JS change it to a number. This forces the state to stay a number.